# Regex get all characters between a character

Tags: javascript, regex

i have a text like this apple man `<span field="apply to|1232sdsdf_nsdnfnln|Data" contenteditable="false"> open the door <span field="apply to|1232sds$df_nsdnfnln|Data"`. i wrote a regex like this to get the items separated by `|`. but it takes only words. If there is characters like `@$%`.

This is the regex i'm using `<span\s+field="([\w\s]+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)`

Comment: so do you want to split by pipe | or something else as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying [`\w+`, which only captures numbers, letters and the underscore](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar.asp), you could specify any amount of characters that [aren't the character that ends the group](https://regex101.com/r/gfnZeU/1) by using a `^`, followed by the characters that won't match, within a `[]`:

```
<span\s+field="([^|]+)\|([^|]+)\|([^"]+)
```

So `[^|]+` will match any at least one character that isn't `|`, and `[^"]+` will match at least one character that isn't `"`.